# Classe Resolver se perdendo por conta de método assíncrono (Angular 11)

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routes

Tenho uma classe Resolver que é chamada na rota de uma página que tem um parâmetro opcional e parece que a rotina se "perde" quando o parâmetro da rota é nulo, onde a rotina está executando os seguintes passos:

1. a classe chama o método **this.fechamentoService.getAll()**;
2. bate no final da função;
3. vai na página tentar carregar a variável que é resultado da leitura do Resolver, não carregando os dados na página;
4. depois volta para a classe Resolver para realizar a finalização com sucesso do método **this.fechamentoService.getAll()**;
5. finaliza a execução sem retornar novamente para a página.

O resultado que eu gostaria de obter é a execução da classe Resolver sendo finalizada uma única vez batendo na linha do 2º "return" que vai carregar os dados enviando para a página.

Como devo ajustar o código para resolver esta questão?

```
@Injectable()
export class MovRealizadaGroupByContaResolver implements Resolve<any[]> {

  private dataReferencia: string;
  constructor( private router: Router,
               private movRealizadaService: MovRealizadaService,
               private fechamentoService: FechamentoService) {}

  resolve(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    this.dataReferencia = activatedRouteSnapshot.params['dataFim'];      
      if(this.dataReferencia){
        return this.movRealizadaService.GetMaxGroupBySaldoConta(this.dataReferencia);
      }else{
        this.fechamentoService.getAll().subscribe(
          success=>{
            this.dataReferencia = DateConvert.formatDateYYYYMMDD(success[0].dataReferencia, '-');
            /*===========================================================================            
            vai na página, executa a leitura da variável resolve e depois vem para cá...
            return this.movRealizadaService.GetMaxGroupBySaldoConta(this.dataReferencia);
            ============================================================================*/
          }
        )
      }
  }//bate aqui primeiro..
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O método `resolve` da sua classe precisa retornar um valor para que a rota possa ser carregada, este é o objetivo do [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), você carregar um valor que você precisa antes de navegar para a rota.

Dentro do else, da sua função, você não está retornando nada. Sugiro que modifique a classe para retornar apenas um observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class MovRealizadaGroupByContaResolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
...
if(this.dataReferencia){
    return of(this.movRealizadaService.GetMaxGroupBySaldoConta(this.dataReferencia));
  } else {
    return this.fechamentoService.getAll()
```

Observe que assim você precisa ajustar o componente que espera o `resolve` para tratar um `Observable`, e não um valor.

Agora, caso você não queira retornar um `Observable` no seu `resolve`, a sua função `getAll()` precisa retornar um valor.